# How to get background color onClick using styled components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to get background colour on Click when user clicks on any page in pagination. When I used simple css then this worked

```
         className ={currentPage === number? "selected":""}
```

when selected was a class in css as //.selected{background-color:red;} // but now I have to use React styled components. How to achieve the same outcome?

//App.tsx//

```
          <Button
          className ={currentPage === number? "selected":""}
          key={number}
          value={number}
        >
        </Button>
```

//AppStyles.ts//

```
  import styled from "styled-components";

  export const Button = styled.button
         `
      ????

       `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same.

```
export const Button = styled.button`
    &.selected { background-color: red; }
`;
```

Comment: Tried that, doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you need the `&` to avoid adding a descendant combinator. Fixed.

Comment: yep.. I have tried that too and doesnt work ;/

Comment: @yo2022 — It works when I test it : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-lu2gs3?file=/index.js